# My async task is blocking other code from running and not outputting anything

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, blocking, .net-4.6.1

Recently I've been converting my node.js bot to C# but I've ran across an problem for some odd reason `public async Task InitCloudCompute()` is **blocking** my other code from running. I got no idea why this is happening and I am fairly new with C#. I would appreciate it if someone could help me solve this issue out. :)

**Edit:** I forgot to say the program starts because I can open the localhost in my browser.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Discord;
using Discord.Commands;
using Discord.WebSocket;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using static Doom.Grid.Bot.Utility.ConsoleGlobals;

namespace Doom
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) => new Program().InitBotAsync()
            .GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        
        private DiscordSocketClient _client;
        private CommandService _commands;
        private IServiceProvider _services;

        public async Task InitBotAsync()
        {
            _client = new DiscordSocketClient();
            _commands = new CommandService();
            _services = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddSingleton(_client)
                .AddSingleton(_commands)
                .BuildServiceProvider();

            _client.Log += _client_internal_Log;

            await InitCloudCompute();
            await RegisterCommandsAsync();
            await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, "Nope"); // TODO: Remove 
                // hard-coded token
            await _client.StartAsync();
            await Task.Delay(-1);
        }

        public async Task InitCloudCompute()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{CCServiceInternalLog} Initializing CCService");
            ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo;
            Process process;

            processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                Arguments = "-console -verbose 5000",
                FileName = "D:\\21CC\\CC-FE4FEB09A756\\CCService.exe"
            };

            process = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = processStartInfo,
                EnableRaisingEvents = true
            };

            process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler
            (
                delegate (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{CCServiceInternalLog} {e.Data.ToString()}");
                }
            );

            process.Start();
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            process.WaitForExit();
            process.CancelOutputRead();
        }

        private Task _client_internal_Log(LogMessage arg)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{DiscordInternalLog} {arg}");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public async Task RegisterCommandsAsync()
        {
            _client.MessageReceived += HandleCommandAsync;
            await _commands.AddModulesAsync(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), _services);
        }

        private async Task HandleCommandAsync(SocketMessage arg)
        {
            var message = arg as SocketUserMessage;
            var context = new SocketCommandContext(_client, message);
            if (message.Author.IsBot) return;

            int argPos = 0;
            if (message.HasStringPrefix(">", ref argPos))
            {
                var result = await _commands.ExecuteAsync(context, argPos, _services);
                if (!result.IsSuccess) Console.WriteLine(result.ErrorReason);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make the main function async as well.

Comment: @Fildor I'll try and let you know how it goes

Comment: That will be just one step of the way. I am just realizing more challenges along tthe way of reading the rest of the code ... :)

Comment: Do you ever get to/past `process.WaitForExit();` ?

Comment: I tried to make main async but it complains "Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point"  `static async Task Main(string[] args) => new Program().InitBotAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();`

Comment: What versions of .net and C# are you using here?

Comment: @HenkHolterman The .net is 4.6.1 and C# is 7.3

Comment: `await Task.Delay(-1);` without a cancellationtoken?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen that is for discord.net i dont remember what exactly it does but i think it keeps the gateway alive

Comment: Then `static async Task Main(string[] args) {  await new Program().InitBotAsync();  }` ought to work.

Comment: The `.GetResult()` could well be the source of your blocking problem. And then `await` will solve that.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I tried that but it still seems to be blocking would you have any idea what else might be blocking it or what I've did wrong with my code?

Comment: Well, how is WaitForExit() doing?   There is nothing async about InitCloudCompute(). There should be a warning when you compile this.

Comment: Also, registering singletons to a ServiceCollection seems really senseless here ... If I had to guess, I'd guess someone took a (or some) examples that were aimed at some sort of Service - typed project template and put those in a project that has been bootstrapped with a Console App project template.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit?view=net-6.0
Process.WaitForExit will block the current thread.

"Sets the period of time to wait for the associated process to exit, and blocks the current thread of execution until the time has elapsed or the process has exited. To avoid blocking the current thread, use the Exited event."

Docs for Task.GetAwaiter similarly say that it is generally for the compiler and not for application use.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.getawaiter?view=net-6.0

So you could create a new task and run it like so

```cs
Task task = Task.Run({new Program().InitBotAsync()});

// And instead of process.WaitForExit() try

process.Exited += new EventHandler(yourHandlerHere);
```

to do the cleanup